# SQL type providers not working correctly for many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, f#, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use the SqlDataConnection type provider in F# to access a database I've created using entity framework code first model defined in C#.

```cs
public class Tag
{
    [Required]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bookmark> TagBMs { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        TagBMs = new HashSet<Bookmark>();
    }
}

public class Bookmark
{
    [Required]
    public int BookmarkId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> BMTags { get; set; }

    public Bookmark()
    {
        BMTags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
}

public class BookmarksContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Bookmark>().HasMany(b => b.BMTags).WithMany(t => t.TagBMs).Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("TagId");
                cs.MapRightKey("BookmarkId");
                cs.ToTable("BookmarkTag");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

When accessing the database in C#, the Tag objects have a "TagBMs" property, and the bookmarks have a "BMTags" property that I can use to add tags to bookmarks and bookmarks to tags. However, when I try to access the same database from F#, these properties do not appear. Instead, the Bookmark objects have a "BookmarkTag" property which returns data from the link table. What do I need to change so that I get the correct properties in F#? I set up the SqlDataConnection type as follows:

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"""Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DatabaseModelAndMigrations.BookmarksContext;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False""">
```

Comment: Why don't you use your C# EF DbContext in your F# code? Would be a lot easier _and_ simpler.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor, I tried your suggestion and by using the C# db context in the f# code and I can use the properties and the many to many relationship works correctly. One small issue with this approach was that there doesn't seem to be a way to easily drop all data from a table  like there was with the F# type provider (I do this in my integration test fixture) but I worked around this by executing SQL "delete from ..." statements directly. If you want to promote your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use SQL type provider, just use your C# EF DbContext from your F# code.

Would be a lot easier and simpler.